# Making IDispose::Dispose() private

Tags: c#, memory-management, dispose

I have an object that contains a file stream. The file stream is to be open for the lifetime of the object. I want the file stream to close when the object has no more references, but *never* before then. If Dispose() is called on the object, the file is disposed, but the object may still have references. Calling other methods after that point would not be safe because the file would be disposed already, so I would need to implement checking at the beginning of each method to ensure that the file is still valid (waste of run time).

It might seem like making Dispose() private would solve this issue, but then again, I'm understanding that the destructor might not be called immediately when the object has no more references - so basically I MUST expose a Dispose() method for the caller to do their own cleanup. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of "smart" memory management, and is there any way around this?

Comment: So you don't trust the users of the object to only Dispose when they no longer need the object?  Why not just re-open the file if `Dispose` has been called previously?

Comment: You don't have to do it manually.  AOP can inject the call: https://github.com/Fody/Janitor

Comment: That would involve checking to see if the file has been disposed previously. It would be better if the object could assume that the file was always open. No unnecessary conditionals.

Comment: That makes no sense as written, never implement your own garbage collector.  You already have one, if the object has no references then it is going to be collected.  The FileStream will automatically be collected as well, no help is needed.

Comment: I'm not implementing my own collector. I was to understand that the destructor is called at the whim of the GC, whenever it feels like it... so if I don't explicitly dispose of the file, it will remain open until the GC is invoked or the Dispose() method is called.

Comment: You need to either choose the `Dispose` pattern and trust your users, or choose garbage collection and live with nondeterministic finalization.  There is no mechanism that forces collection (or disposal) as soon as all references are gone.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no more references to your object, it will be garbage collected together with the inner file stream. During the GC, the [file stream's finalizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx) will be executed and the file will be closed. You don't need `Dispose()` to achieve it. The problem is that you don't know when the GC will run. It seems your object has a long lifetime, so it will probably be in [generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#generations) 2. It might take a long time for gen 2 GC to run.

You should implement `IDisposable` and check the state of your object before every call. If the object was disposed, throw `ObjectDisposedException`.